# How to add .shp file to google cloud platform postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to add a local .shp file into the google cloud SQL. Can I use the shp2pgsql command?

I have successfully connected to the database using cloud shell.

[cloud shell info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5IdV.png)

Comment: shp2pgsql isn't a command, but a program. You cannot run it from inside of postgres. Exit the database and execute it from your console ;) cheers

Comment: thank you for your reply. Does this command available on the google cloud platform?

Comment: That I cannot tell. it normally comes with the postgis package insalled in your OS ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JimJones in the comments, `shp2pgsql` isn't a command, but a program so you cannot run it from inside of postgres and since you cannot access the instances in Cloud SQL directly (You can only access the DB on the instance, not the instance where the DB is located itself) this is not possible.

I have not found any documentation or article online on how to add `.shp` files to Cloud SQL, so I assume that this is not implemented for that product. You can try to open a feature request so that this can be consider and implemented by Google's product team in their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) and if this is possible in some other way that can provide you some guidance.

Comment: Thank you! I searched online and did not find any article on how to add .shp to google cloud SQL. I was wondering that shp2pgsql is a command installed with postgis extension or it comes with postgresql?

Comment: It worked for me. The difficult part is to connect with the google cloud platform.

Comment: @Zen How did you managed to connect it to Cloud SQL? Can you share more details? To you followup question, I would say that shp2pgsql comes with the extension, since it is oriented into spacial and geographic objects so this makes sense, although I can't confirm it.

Comment: I managed to connect with google cloud using shp2pgsql. I added some codes like `sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem houstaddr=XX.XXX.XXX.XXX`

Answer (score 0):

You can use geopandas for this and execute the code inside a JupyterLab AI notebook.

```
def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
    conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
        'host', 
        "pg8000",
        user='user',
        password='password',
        db='database'
    )
    return conn

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

gdf = gpd.read_file('gs://bucket/file.shp')
gdf.to_postgis('table_name', engine)
```

But pg8000 is still in alpha and needs to be adjusted in order to make it work, see https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000/issues/75.